# Why do so many foss libraries make their classes public and not final?

Tags: java, design-patterns, class-design

Before you jump on me with an obvious answer, let me qualify the question and say, not all classes are sub classable.

- Sub classing should be a carefully thought out extra not a default property of all classes.
- It could be argued classes should be final by default and not final if one really wants that.

I can think of many advantages for package private classes.

- if the class is not really for my viewing and just a helper that i should consider a implementation detail, making it non public means it wont come up when i search for classes by name or implementations of an interface in my ide.
- it also means that if everything but the exported interfaces are public examining the api while browsing the library jar files becomes much simpler as there is less noise. I no longer see internal implementation stuff.
- there is no need to worry about sub classes outside your package.
- for the users the practical benefit means that methods they need are probably also going to be grouped together under one interface/class rather than being scattered around in other public classes which means less cluter and there are less places to look and less handles too manage.

So why dont people take advantage of these facilities ?

Answer (score 3):

There are languages e.g. python in which everything is public and nothing is final. That doesn't mean they are living in hell and modules are impossible to use and maintain. Quite the contrary.

Software engineering is tricky. Many times we are fighint strawmen in our minds. That can be fun,  we chase the ideal regardless of practical benefits - if we have the time. If you are a single person that's responsible for hundreds of classes, being a perfectionist will drive you crazy.

Comment: Which is why nobody writes real systems in languages like Python. Scripting languages are for quick and nasty jobs not big arse complex systems. Big systems in general are written in type safe languages because people hate headaches and confusion caused by stuff like this.

Comment: not so sure about that. as long as there are a lot of supporting test cases, dynamic languages are not a hassle (with a good IDE)

Comment: Steven. Its a fact, the reason scripting langs are dynamic is because if one is writing a program that is at most a few dozen lines then there is no need for types because you can see and understand in front of you and because if there were interfaces and you had to implement and satisfy them this would make the program that much longer. However as things grow, type safety is your friend, because it means the compiler can add an extra layer and verify at your code looks right to begin w/. You can also cleanup your code by refactoring or improving naming stuff that is not possible in

Comment: scripting languages because refactoring is simply a search and replace and one cant tell if you got only the callers of some target or all functions w/ the same name.

Comment: @mP: But people *do* write real systems in scripting languages, all your points notwithstanding. By "real system" I mean over a million lines and used in production controlling safety-critical equipment, such as in a factory production line, on an oil rig or aboard a naval ship. I know of such things in deployment. Your argument is thus full of it by demonstration of (multiple) counter-examples.

Comment: Of course there will always be some examples of scripting in large systems, but an unbiased survey will demonstrate tht in the end, statically typed languages like java or c# will faily easily be the vast majority or such systems. Its no coincidence that Microsoft dropped support for the Iron family of languages and remains focused on c# rather than a scripting language.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, circumstances change.
What you think is not subclassable now, may be required for subclassing later.
A lot of more "fluffy"design choices (such as making a class final) are considered over engineering later when you find out that in fact you should be subclassing.

Most API designs take into account extendability.

Comment: "What you think is not subclassable now, may be required for subclassing later". It is easy to convert a class from `final` to non-`final`, because this can not break any code that uses the library. But doing the opposite breaks any code that defines a derived class.

Comment: The problem is you make a class which is not designed for subclassing and forget to make it final. By "not designed" I mean, you just didn't think of it, and this may lead to hard to find bugs. With a non-final class, the fact that method `a` calls method `b` is no implementation detail anymore, and should be documented and never changed. Funny things happen when `a` is a constructor, as it calls `b` on not yet fully constructed object (example `Random.setSeed` called from the ctor).

Comment: @Raedwald, which is exactly why you should make your classes final and package private today. If they are useful and should be subclassable then you can always do that at a later stage. Onc eyou release something as public and not final someone somewhere will find and do the sub class thing which prevents you from adding final. etc.

Comment: @Steven Most api designers do not take extensibility into consideration. java.util.Stack, java.util.Properties are perfect examples of crap that could have been avoided if Hashtable were final or package private. Sub classing is most of the time evil, extracting an interface that picks only the right methods is almost always a better solution. The reason ppl like sub classing is laziness, they think they are saving time, until later on when they come back and realise they are stuck and cant change a class because someone has sub classed it.

Comment: @mP: that is the fault of the person subclassing when they shouldnt be. I am arguing for a more flexible and what consider future-proof design. Adding not 100% required restrictions is usually just fighting straw men and are taken out later. As for as people saying you can just remove it later, later is sometimes too late as the poor dev trying to use your api/library has hit the final brick wall already and has either moved away from your api or has broken it in some more ugly way to get what they need done.

Comment: @Steven no way - the original should have prevented it to begin w/ by final or making the class package private.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of whether classes should be final or not by default, it's a heavily debated point for which there's not really a "right" answer. Java chose to do it one way, C# another, different people think different languages got it right and wrong.

Personally, I like the way classes are extendible by default, if people want to make them final then they can, it's only a keyword away. But allowing sub classing just adds more flexibility in my view, sure I don't have to extend every non-final object under the sun but if I want to add some degree of specific behaviour then that option's there for me to do so. Yes, composition could be used (and indeed should be used in some cases) but that doesn't and shouldn't rule out sub classing as an option. There's many cases when the sub-classed object fulfils the is-a relationship with the parent, and in that case it's the right way to go. Admittedly though this has been misused in the past, even in the Java API (properties for instance is not really a hashtable.) But if you're trying to change the language to stop people being stupid - well, they'll always find a way around it!

As for making classes package private, for me this option would be far more useful if packages were hierarchical rather than flat. Yes, they're hierarchical in description but something declared package private in org.me can't be accessed from org.me.subpackage, which I often feel the need to do. Fortunately with the addition of superpackages we might see this option being better used!

Comment: The last point about visibility in sub packages is of course a problem. I thought i heard there was going to be a jsr about introducing a keyword or something to fix that but who knows what happened there.

Comment: With package private classes, they would have their factories in one class with static methods - think java.util.Collections. There is no need to know the names of the implementations the various synchronized/unmodifable, singleton etc methods use, they are hidden away knowing the return type is enough - the name of the class behind the scenes is not important or necessary.

Comment: "Java chose to do it one way, C# another" No classes aren't sealed/final in C# by default. Only methods are non virtual by default.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your supposed advantages of libraries not supporting sub-classing is not backed by my experience.
2. Java doesn't have delegation, thin subclasses are often used as adapters or method interceptors.
   It is more readable to do it in code than doing it by using a reflective proxy.

Things change. Software that can change is easier to work with. Sometimes this takes radical improvements like Java 8's default methods. These neatly fix adding methods to interfaces after the interfaces are widely used.

Comment: Thats b/s java does support delegation, itsnot that hard to generate the forwaring methods w/ an ide or gasp typuing them in yourself.

Comment: @mP yes and what you describe is exactly what I'm describing. Delegation via a thin subclass wrapper. If all library classes were final you could not do this. C# has the delegation mechanism which works around classes being final by default.  I personally think Java and Smalltalk get it right.

Comment: If you program to interfaces rather than sub classing you can always delegate, then final doesnt screw you up.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is just because thinking what should NOT be EVER extended takes lots of brain effort.

For most of small and medium-sized components and frameworks good guess is that to deprecate and keep the abused/overused method/class is easier and more user-friendly than thinking of most probable and some quite improbable usecases and still occasionally closing something which then needs some dirty delegation/decoration instead of simple extension.

On my practice only Java's Spring really bothered me with this kind of preventive closure (which results in a lot clearer API after several micro releases I think).

I had a quote of R. Martin on this matter here:

http://java.akraievoy.org/2009/03/openclosed-principle-strategic-closure.html

Answer (score 0):

- modifiers **public and final are from different categories**, putting them to single sentence is not a good start when you want to make things clear
- as for **final** - **requirements change** and after some time you can find yourself in need to subclass some final class too, plus **not all libraries/frameworks can crate proxies to final classes**
- as for **package access** - **could make refactoring more complicated**, but yes, if you produce some library, to not publish internal classes is a good "pattern"

Comment: If everything is an interface there is no need to worry about proxy final classes.